# How can I parse a date from file then insert a line after that matched date in bash?

Tags: bash, date

My problem is that I am not sure how to read and parse a date and then append a line after that date to a file. I have a log file and want to add reboots according to when they have happened.

The log file looks like this and my last reboot was 21:15..

```
[2014-05-12 20:49] upgraded something
[2014-05-12 20:49] upgraded something else
[2014-05-12 20:50] upgraded yet something else
[2014-05-12 21:51] upgraded something
[2014-05-12 21:51] upgraded other something
[2014-05-12 21:52] upgraded that something
```

I want it to look something like this..

```
[2014-05-12 20:49] upgraded something
[2014-05-12 20:49] upgraded something else
[2014-05-12 20:50] upgraded yet something else
REBOOTED
[2014-05-12 21:51] upgraded something
[2014-05-12 21:51] upgraded other something
[2014-05-12 21:52] upgraded that something
```

My plan is to use `who -b` or `last reboot` to get the times when the reboots occurred but after that I am not sure. Filtering out the dates are no issue. I'll just use `grep -o` but as it's not an exact date to match it becomes difficult. So I am guessing I need to send the output from `who -b` to `date` and then match for that in the log file. When closest date found append "REBOOTED".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here's the sample code.
I assume that you are working on linux's GNU date command,
and your log is sorted in time order.

`BOOT_TIME` and `TMP2` would be something like `2014-05-12 21:51`.

see http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html what `${VAR#}` and `${VAR$}` means

NOTE: `who -b` does not seem to work if there is no user login'ed .
see the following URL for more details:
https://superuser.com/questions/263486/linux-getting-date-time-of-system-startup

```
#!/bin/bash
BOOT_TIME=$(date +"%F %H:%M" -d "$(cut -f1 -d. /proc/uptime) seconds ago")
REBOOT_FLAG=""
while read line;do
  TMP1=${line%]*}
  TMP2=${TMP1#[}
  if [ -z "$REBOOT_FLAG" ] && [ "$TMP2" \> "$BOOT_TIME" ];then
    echo REBOOTED
    REBOOT_FLAG="true"
  fi
 echo "$line"
done
```

use it like

```
$ ./this-script.sh < logfile
```

Comment: Thanks! It worked as expected. I just needed to remake it into a function for my script. Would probably never have figured it out by myself.. so thanks a lot! ;)